# ValidateAntiForgeryToken causing an exception on our staging server on a specific form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

This is a very unusual error. In our MVC application, we use anti forgery tokens on every single post. They all work flawlessly without any issues, on local machines and when deployed to our staging server.

However there is one form we have where it is throwing an exception `anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid`. The data is definitely there in the POST and the cookie exists too. There is no difference I can see from anywhere else on the site.

I've been browsing google for the past hour looking for ideas, but nothing has come up. Does anyone have any suggestions how I might try debugging this? The controller is here:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UpdateKittens(KittenViewModel KVM)
        {
...
```

and

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>

            <%= Html.EditorFor(model => model)%>

        </fieldset>

        <% } %>
```

Any suggestions welcome.

I should emphasise that it works fine locally, it's only on our stage server that this specific form doesn't work.

Comment: Do you call `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` multiple times while rendering that view?

Comment: As far as I can see, it calls it a single time as the above code is exactly what we're running. Can confirm from the source that only one __RequestVerificationToken hidden field is present, and it's within the form.